# Jquery mobile to add panels after loading file to populate a div

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, panel

OK so I am using $_POST to submit a form in jquery mobile and it works like this:

```
if($_POST['i']){?>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script>
        $( "#info" ).load( "file.php?&information=<?=$_POST['i']?>");
    </script>
<?}?>
```

file.php has something like this:

```
<a href="#panel1" role="button">info 1</a>
<a href="#panel2" role="button">info 2</a>

<div data-role="panel" id="panel1" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" class="panels">
    Text 1
</div>

<div data-role="panel" id="panel2" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" class="panels">
    Text 2
</div>
```

I want to load file.php to fill #info. Then I want to keep the  links in that div and move the panels to after the footer of the containing page (#footer). My problem is that when I try to add something after the load like this:

```
<script>
    $( "#info" ).load( "file.php?i=<?=$_POST['i']?>");
    $("#footer").after(".panels");
</script>
```

Nothing appends. I can append other things after the footer like:

```
$("#footer").after("TEST");
```

So I guess the problem is that anything inside the loaded div is unavailable. How do I get at it?

Comment: looks like you want jquery detach https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Even if I go like this $(".panels" ).detach(); I can't remove the panels from within #info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
<script>
$( "#info" ).load( "file.php?i=<?=$_POST['i']?>", function() {
var p = $("#info").find( ".panels" ).detach();
$( "#footer" ).after(p);
});
</script>
```

Comment: The divs aren't removed from within #info when I do this, do I need to somehow refresh after the load to let jquery know there is more in that #info div?

Comment: sorry, i didn't account for dynamic content. I made a change in the answer.

Comment: This works (the HTML is all in the right place) but the panels are visible by default down by the footer and clicking on the links doesn't open or close them. Do I need to refresh the view somehow?

Comment: I added $(function() {$( "[data-role=panel]" ).panel().enhanceWithin();});